# independent identically distribution(iid) gaussian normal matrix

Tags: matlab

I am writting a matlab code and I need an iid gaussian normal matrix how can I produce this?
plz.
in this site I found matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M) but doesn't work and explaine.

p

Answer (score 1):

To generate an M times N matrix of Gaussian iid random variables, with mean mu and standard deviation sigma, you only need

```
result = mu + sigma*randn(M,N);
```